# How can I solve $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{(1+\frac{k}{x})^x}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I solve $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{(1+\frac{k}{x})^x}}$ using $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to +\infty} {(1+\frac{1}{x})^x = e}}$? What should I do with the constant "$k$?

Comment: where is $k$ ? in $\mathbb R$ ? in $\mathbb N$ ?

Comment: I think $k$ is in $ℝ$, or else it wouldn't be continuous right?

Comment: As long as $x$ is in $\mathbb{R}$, that's good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that I'll be assuming $k > 0$.
Observe that
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1 + \dfrac{k}{x}\right)^x &= \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1 + \dfrac{k}{x}\right)^{kx/k}\\
&\overset{y=x/k}{=} \lim_{y\to\infty}\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{y}\right)^{ky}\\
&= \lim_{y\to\infty}\left(\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{y}\right)^{y}\right)^k\\
&= \left(\lim_{y\to\infty}\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{y}\right)^{y}\right)^k\\
&= e^k
\end{align}$$

The interchange of $(\cdot)^k$ and $\lim$ was possible because the function $x\mapsto x^k$ is continuous.

The answer to your question should now be clear. (The function $x \mapsto 1/x$ is continuous on $(0, \infty)$ and thus, you should get $e^{-k}$.)

---

**Edit:** Adding the case $k \le 0$ as well.
Nothing needs to be said for $k = 0$. It is clearly $1$.

Assume that $k < 0$. Before proceeding further, let us prove the following lemma.

**Lemma.** $\displaystyle\lim_{y \to -\infty}\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{y}\right)^{y} = e.$

*Proof.* Consider the limit 
$$L = \lim_{y\to-\infty}y\ln\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{y}\right) =  \lim_{y\to-\infty}\dfrac{\ln\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{y}\right)}{1/y}.$$
We can evaluate it using L'Hospital since the rightmost limit is of the form $0/0$. This gives us
$$L= \lim_{y\to-\infty}\dfrac{\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{y}\right)(-1/y^2)}{-1/y^2} = 1.$$

From this, it follows that the original limit was $e^L = e$.

---

With this lemma in place, the result for $k < 0$ follows by again making the substitution $y = x/k$ but now noting that $y \to -\infty$ instead.
Interestingly, the answer in all these cases turns out to be $\boxed{e^{-k}}$.

Comment: if $k$ was negative, I would have to use $y=-x/k$?

Comment: @HengWei: You still can use the substitution that I used but then you would have $\lim_{y\to-\infty}$. However, your substitution might lead to a better calculation.

Comment: @egreg: That is not true. I have used it to conclude that $y \to \infty$ after the substitution $y = x/k$.

Comment: How can I calculate the limit if $\lim_{y \to -\infty}$ ?

Comment: For example $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to +\infty} (1-\frac{5}{x})^x}$

Comment: @HengWei: Updated the answer to include all cases.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for $k \in \mathbb{R}$, you just have to use $\ln(1+a)= a+O(a^2)$ for small a:
$$
\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{1}{(1+\frac{k}{x})^x}}
= \lim_{x \to +\infty} (1+\frac{k}{x})^{-x} = \lim_{x \to +\infty}  e^{-x  \ln{ (1+\frac{k}{x})}}  = \lim_{x \to +\infty}  e^{-x     \frac{k}{x} } =    e^{-k} 
$$